# Webpack image can't find module

Tags: typescript, image, webpack

I am trying to export my images by doing so:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

And here is my `index.ts` file:

```
import {css} from 'lit-element';
import ErrorIcon from './assets/icons/error.svg';
export const iconStyles = css`
  .icon-error {
    background-image : src("${ErrorIcon.src}");
  }
  .icon-warning {
     background-image : src("/assets/icons/warning.svg");
  }`;
```

When I run build I get the following error:

> TS2307: Cannot find module './assets/icons/error.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the issue apprently in typescript you have to add a file that looks like this:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

[Source](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets)

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
background-image : url("${ErrorIcon.src}");
```